# Copying a Zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have only a very basic grasp of Zend Framework. I have been asked to copy an existing project (made with version 1.12) in order to rebrand it and use it for other clients.

I have copied the entire project and uploaded it to a different hosting space. Am I wrong in thinking that it should just work because all the files are still in the same place relative to eachother? I have read elsewhere that it should be simply a case of copying the entire project but it is not working for me.

The directory structure is like this:

```
project
- application
- - configs
- - - application.ini
- - controllers
- - - helpers
- - - ErrorController
- - docs 
- - forms
- - models
- - - DbTable
- - modules
- - - admin
- - - controllers
- - - payment
- - - touradmin
- - - - controllers
- - - - - IndexController
- - - - - BookingController
- - - - forms
- - - - models
- - - - views
- - - - - filters
- - - - - helpers
- - - - - layouts
- - - - - scripts
- - - - - - index
- - - - - - - index.phtml
- - - tourview
- - plugins
- - services
- - template
- - views
- - bootstrap.php
- my.project.ie
- - tourmanager
- - - index.php
- - index.php
- library
- logs
- stats
```

I have copied everything exactly as it was. On the original site my.project.ie is the public folder (i think) - there isn't a folder called public like most zend projects have, in this case my.project.ie is the 'public' folder. If I load it in the browser I get the generic "Welcome To The Zend Framework" message. The main activity on the site occurs at my.project.ie/tourmanager/touradmin. I'm guessing that the IndexController in the touradmin module is what happens when you visit this url.

After copying the files and setting my.project.ie as the web directory for the domain I also get this Zend welcome screen. However if I visit the new my.project.ie/tourmanager/ I get a message saying

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/shane/sites/project/my.project.ie/tourmanager/index.php on line 34
```

I can get the "Welcome to zend framework" screen to appear  at my.project.ie/tourmanager/ by editing  the line

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

to

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));
```

but if I go to my.project.ie/tourmanager/touradmin I get a "404 Not Found" page. I don't know if that's a step in the right direction or not.

I have also tried adding resources.frontController.baseUrl = '/sites/project/my.project.ie' to the application.ini.

Is there some simple step I'm missing?

EDIT: 
here is the tourmanager/index.php

```
<?php

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'testing') {
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

}


// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "On the original site my.project.ie is the public folder"? Are you saying that the original project had a folder called `public`, but in this copy you've renamed that to `my.project.ie`? Could you add the contents of the tourmanager/index.php file to your question (if it's short)?

Comment: @TimFountain I have edited the post to indicate that instead of a folder called 'public' the project uses a folder called 'my.project.ie' as the folder most zend projects would call 'public'. At least, that's what i think is going on. I have also added the contents of contents of the tourmanager/index.php. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that looks like a standard public/index.php file but I don't really understand why it's in a subfolder. Is the index.php in the parent folder the same? What do you get if you visit my.project.ie/touradmin/ ?

Comment: In cpanel I have set the 'my.project.ie' directory as the web directory for this domain so when I go to hllp://my.project.ie the 'my.project.ie' directory is the one that you get - i hope that makes sense. If I go to hllp://my.project.ie/touradmin I get a "404 Not Found" page. At hllp://my.project.ie/tourmanager I get "Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .... tourmanager/index.php"

Comment: The index.php in the parent folder is missing the "Define application environment" bit and starts with "Define path to application directory"

Comment: Yup, that's okay though - you'll notice that in the index.php you posted most of that code is there twice. In the old project, how is most of the functionality accessed? Through http://my.project.ie/tourmanager or a different path?

Comment: Most things happen through my.project.ie/tourmanager/touradmin which I think refers to the touradmin module

Comment: Maybe you should try to take original index.php and .htaccess from Zend (download from their webpage) and put it in public folder (well my.project.ie should work too) to see what happens. Be also sure to put Zend library in library folder (or add it to include path)